# openstack-install fails to bring up public/external interface using 14.04

Tags: maas, openstack-autopilot

I have a MAAS server with multiple nodes ready.  Two of the nodes have public/external interfaces.

the `openstack-install` command results in a juju bootstrap failure. This occurs because the public/external interface on the maas node is not brought up.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the interfaces on these two nodes after commissioning? If you did, can you try commissioning them again in their current state and then try to bootstrap with juju manually?

Instructions on how to configure juju with MAAS can be found here: https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.20/config-maas